# Can we update the reputation under Users search in real time?

Tags: support, reputation, users-page

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a missing feature, but I've noticed that when I search for Users under the large "Users" button under questions, the reputation scores there are generally out of date.

If it is not too difficult to fix, would it be possible to fix this reputation display?

Comment: Caching. Wait a bit and it will update.

Comment: @Doorknob, actually on SO my reputation was more than 6 months old when I search for it under Users tag.

Comment: That sounds like there is another user with the same name as you

Comment: @Doorknob, Nope, I click through it, and it is me.

Comment: You are looking at the Week or Month tab.

Comment: What @David said

Comment: @DavidRobinson, Thanks. I did not even notice the sub-tabs.

Comment: Can someone explain all the downvoting on the question, which seems at odds with the very useful answer it produced for anyone else who did not notice the part of the GUI that I missed?

Comment: @merlin2011 [Votes are different on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) Most likely most of the downvotes express disagreement with the original feature request expressed in your question. However, even if the same guidelines were applied here as on SO (and other non-meta sites), this might still be downvoted as an expression of some users' beliefs about how much research effort went into the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the Week or Month tab, which shows how much you earned that week or month. Click on the All button on the top right.

> [image]